# (Proof Check) Radius of Convergence Theorem: Special Case $R = \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

Here is my attempt at a proof that for a complex power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, if $\limsup|a_n|^{1/n} = 0$, then the power series converges absolutely on all of $\mathbb{C}$. I'm out of practice with convergence proofs, so I could use some verification that my argument is correct.

Fix $z$ and pick $0 < \epsilon < 1/|z|$, so that $\epsilon|z| < 1$. Then we can find some $N$  such that $|a_n|^{1/n} < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$, which implies $|a_n| < \epsilon^n$ for all $n \geq N$. We then have $$|a_nz^n| = |a_n||z|^n < \epsilon^n|z|^n = (\epsilon|z|)^n.$$
The geometric series $\sum(\epsilon|z|)^n$ converges, and thus $\sum |a_n z^n|$ converges as well.

Comment: It looks fine to me.